# The value of $a+b=ab=a^2-b^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a+b=ab=a^2-b^2$ and $a$ and $b$ are real numbers then what do all of the expressions evaluate to?

1. $(1+\sqrt5)/2$
2. $(3+\sqrt5)/2$
3. 2
4. $\sqrt5$

Not sure at all how to find the answer. I tried $a=ab/b$ and $a=(a^2-b^2)/b$ but after that I am lost.

Comment: It looks like this was intended for [Math.SE] -- would you like me to move your question to that site?

Comment: sorry , yes please

Comment: You can have $a=b=0$ which is not one of the given solutions.

Comment: Hint: $a+b=(a-b)(a+b)$

Comment: Note that $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$, giving either $a-b=0$ or $a-b=1$...

Answer (score 3):

Any time you see $a^2-b^2$ you should think $(a+b)(a-b)$.  Here if $a+b \neq 0$ you can divide it out to get $1=a-b$  Then $a=b+1, a+b=2b+1=(b+1)b$ and feed it to the quadratic formula.

If $a+b=0$ we must have $a=b=0$ and the sum is again $0$, which should have been one of the choices.